# Flash Gun Simulation

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, loops, actionscript, reload

I wanted to know how to make a sound keep playing whilst the mouse is down e.g.machine gun bullets being fired (not on a click), and when the sound completes, I want the reload sound to play on a click?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in sound's [play](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play%28%29) method is the loop count. You can specify a large value for this. `play` method returns `SoundChannel` object. In your mouse up listener you can use this SoundChannel's [stop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play%28%29) method to stop the sound.

```
// instance variable to remember the channel
private var channel:SoundChannel;

private function onMouseDown(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    // remember channel and start looping
    channel = snd.play(0, 1000000);
}

private function onMouseUp(evt:MouseEvent):void {
   // stop the sound stated in mouse down 
   channel.stop();
}
```